Are generic filters in the sense of forcing generic points in some topological space?
Recall that a filter of a preordered set $A$ is a subset $F \subseteq A$ such that:

$F$ is inhabited, i.e. there exists $a \in F$.

$F$ is upward-closed, i.e. if $a \in F$ and $a \le a' \in A$ then $a' \in F$.

$F$ is downward-directed, i.e. if $a_0 \in F$ and $a_1 \in F$ then there exists $a' \in F$ such that $a' \le a_0$ and $a' \le a_1$.


For example, for any $a \in A$, the subset $\{ a' \in A : a \le a' \}$ is a filter of $A$.
Filters of that form are said to be principal.
Let $\mathscr{F} (A)$ be the set of filters of $A$, partially ordered by reverse inclusion.
Then there is an evident monotone map $A \to \mathscr{F} (A)$ sending each element to the principal filter it generates, and it is an embedding modulo equivalence.
We topologise $\mathscr{F} (A)$ by declaring $J \subseteq \mathscr{F} (A)$ to be open iff
$$J = \{ F \in \mathscr{F} (A) : \exists a \in I . a \in F \}$$
for some downward-closed $I \subseteq A$.
By considering principal filters, we see that the poset of open subsets of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ is naturally isomorphic to the poset of downward-closed subsets of $A$ (partially ordered by inclusion).
Put another way, the map $A \to \mathscr{F} (A)$ induces an isomorphism between the frame of open subsets of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ and the Alexandrov topology of $A$.
Now recall that, given a family $D$ of downward-dense downward-closed subsets of $A$, a filter $F \subseteq A$ is $D$-generic if $F$ meets every element of $D$.
On the other hand, a generic point of a topological space is any point whose closure is the whole space.
Question.
Are these two notions of genericity related?
For example, given $D$, is there some "natural" continuous injection $X \to \mathscr{F} (A)$ (resp. continuous surjection $\mathscr{F} (A) \to X$) such that a $D$-generic filter of $A$ is precisely an image (resp. preimage) of a generic point of $X$?

In the simplest case where $D = \{ A \}$, every filter of $A$ is $D$-generic, yet in general there are non-generic points of $\mathscr{F} (A)$, so in the case of a continuous injection $X \to \mathscr{F} (A)$ we should not require $X$ to be a subspace.
Observe that a filter $F \subseteq A$ meets a subset $S \subseteq A$ if and only if $F$ meets the downward-closure of $S$, and $F$ meets a downward-closed $I \subseteq A$ if and only if $F$ is in the open subset of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ corresponding to $I$.
Therefore, given $D$, the set of $D$-generic filters of $A$ is precisely the intersection of the dense open subsets of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ corresponding to the elements of $D$.
So if the continuous surjection approach is the right way, there should be some "natural" continuous surjection $\mathscr{F} (A) \to X$ that collapses this intersection to a generic point while perhaps leaving everything else alone.
Or maybe it is just a coincidence that the same word is used for unrelated concepts...?

I mean, it seems more that $D$-generic filters should correspond to generic points in a weaker topology on $\mathscr{F}(A)$, namely the topology generated by those open sets corresponding to $D$, rather than any subspace or any quotient.

(Though if $D$ is finite, a quotient does work - just collapse all $D$-generic filters to one point and collapse all other filters to another point.)

Right. But $\mathscr{F} (A)$ is sober (so generic points are unique!), so any weaker topology on the same set should soberify to a quotient, right?

I don’t know enough about sober spaces to know, but if you just want generic points to be unique, you can just take the Kolmogorov quotient, no?

Ah, I think I see what you are saying. Indeed, it won't necessarily be a topological quotient but there should be a continuous surjection.

Requiring $X$ to be a continuous image of $\mathscr{F}(A)$ is definitely fine, yeah, and you can even ask the generic point to be unique. But I don’t see how one can ensure this is a topological quotient, yes.

I think your proposal is correct: $D$-generic filters correspond precisely to the generic points after re-topologising $\mathscr{F} (A)$ with the topology generated by the open sets corresponding to $D$. It seems we don't even need $D$ to be a family of dense subsets – the finite intersection property appears to be enough. If you post an answer with the details I will accept.

As requested by OP, here are my comments, re-organized into an answer:
While this is neither a quotient, nor a subspace of $\mathscr{F}(A)$, one can re-topologize $\mathscr{F}(A)$ with a weaker topology s.t. generic points in this new topology are exactly $D$-generic filters. Indeed, as the OP already observed, $D$-generic filters are exactly points in $\mathscr{F}(A)$ which are in the intersection of all open sets corresponding to elements of $D$. Note that the set of generic points in a topological space is exactly the intersection of all nonempty open sets. If a subbasis $B$ for the topology is given, it is not hard to check that the set of generic points is also exactly the intersection of all nonempty elements of $B$. Combining the above two facts, we see that if we re-topologize $\mathscr{F}(A)$ by choosing the topology generated by all those open sets corresponding to $D$, we get a topology weaker than the original topology on $\mathscr{F}(A)$, and in which the generic points are exactly $D$-generic filters.
As an added remark, if we want to collapse all $D$-generic filters to a single generic point, we can simply take the Kolmogorov quotient of the topology above. Also, in case $D$ is finite, we can actually get an $X$ that’s a topological quotient of $\mathscr{F}(A)$ with the original topology. Indeed, the open sets corresponding to elements of $D$ are dense, so as $D$ is finite, their intersection, i.e., the set of $D$-generic filters, is also open dense. To construct $X$, just collapse all $D$-generic filters to a single point $0$ and all other filters to a second point $1$. Then $0$ is an open point since its inverse image, the set of $D$-generic filters, is open. It is also dense since, again, the set of $D$-generic filters is dense. Thus, you get the Sierpiński space, with the unique generic point corresponding to $D$-generic filters. (There is an edge case of all filters being $D$-generic, in which case $X$ is just a singleton space instead of the Sierpiński space.)

(Remarks from the constructive and localic points of view.)
Let $D$ be any subset of downward-closed subsets of $A$ that is closed under finitary intersections.
This generates a subframe of the frame of downward-closed subsets of $A$: say a downward-closed subset of $A$ is $D$-open iff it is a (possibly infinitary) union of elements of $D$.
Let $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ be the locale corresponding to the frame of $D$-open downward-closed subsets of $A$.
This is a spatial locale: indeed, the subframe inclusion means we have a locale epimorphism $\mathscr{F} (A) \to \mathscr{F} (A, D)$, so we may think of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ as a quotient of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ retopologised with a weaker topology.
Anyway, every filter of $A$ defines a point of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$, though this correspondence may not be bijective.
Recall that a sublocale of a locale $X$ is dense if and only if the corresponding nucleus $j$ has the property that $j (\bot_X) = \bot_X$.
Thus, a filter $F \subseteq A$ corresponds to a generic point of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ if and only if, for every $D$-open downward-closed subset $I \subseteq A$, $I \cap F = \emptyset$ implies $I = \emptyset$; thus, $F$ corresponds to a generic point of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ if and only if, for every element $I$ of $D$, $I \cap F = \emptyset$ implies $I = \emptyset$.
Notice that the above conceals a double negation in the case where every element of $D$ is non-empty: in that case, $F$ corresponds to a generic point of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ if and only if, for every element $I$ of $D$, $\lnot \forall_A a (a \notin I \cap F)$.
As any constructivist knows, $\lnot \forall \lnot$ is weaker than $\exists$.
Rather, we should consider strongly dense sublocales, which are the ones corresponding to nuclei $j$ such that $j (u) = u$ for all $u = \bigvee \{ \top_X \mid \psi \}$ where $\psi$ is a truth value.
Say a point is strongly generic if it is strongly dense as a sublocale.
Then a filter $F \subseteq A$ corresponds to a strongly generic point of $\mathscr{F} (A, D)$ if and only if, for every $D$-open downward-closed subset $I \subseteq A$ and every truth value $\psi$,
$$( \exists_A a (a \in I \cap F) \text{ implies } \psi ) \text{ if and only if } \forall_A a (a \in I \text{ implies } \psi )$$
but
$$\forall_A a (a \in I \text{ implies } \psi ) \text{ if and only if } (\exists_A a (a \in I) \text{ implies } \psi )$$
thus, $F$ corresponds to a strongly generic point of $\mathscr{F} (A)$ if and only if, for every element $I$ of $D$,
$$\exists_A a (a \in I \cap F) \text{ if and only if } \exists_A a (a \in I)$$
or more simply, $F$ meets every inhabited element of $D$, which is more or less the definition of $D$-generic filter.
